# matplotlib how to set plot size (with dpi), not figure size

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I could find a way to set a figure size with dpi

```
px = 1/plt.rcParams['figure.dpi']
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(1580*px, 25*px))
```

(reference: https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/figure_size_units.html)

```
            fig = plt.figure(figsize=(1580*px, 25*px))
            plt.plot(xx, y[0], label='min')
            plt.plot(xx, y[1], label='max')
            plt.yticks(y_ticks, y_tick_labels)
            plt.ylim(top=y_max)
            plt.legend()
```

However, how do you set the plot size?
I want my plot or graph to be full of (1580px, 25px)
but if I set the figure size and plot graphs using the above code, then the graph does not fit the figure (1580px, 25px). Even worse, labels or ticks are not shown well in the figure like below.
[image]

I want my graph size to be the above white space size( for example, 1580px, 25px) and then draw ticks and labels outside the white space (then figure size should be bigger than the given plot size). But I couldn't find a way to set the plot size. I could only find a way to set the figure size.

Comment: If I understand it right, you want to specify the size of `Axes` in pixels, right? If so, maybe you can try `subplots_adjust` to give a spcified size for an axes.

Comment: Matplotlib doesn’t size things this way as usually people want the whole figure to fit a physical space, regardless of dpi.  Is there a motivation behind you wanting this precision in the size of the axes?

Comment: The way you ask the question is rather unclear, but it is a very interesting question! I also want to set the (sub)plot size rather than the figsize so that the plot sizes are consistent even when I have figures with different amounts of subplots. Maybe you can rephrase your question?

Answer (score 0):

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


def axes_with_pixels(width, height, margin=0.2):
    px = 1/plt.rcParams['figure.dpi']
    fig_width, fig_height = np.array([width, height]) / (1 - 2 * margin)
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(fig_width*px, fig_height*px))
    fig.subplots_adjust(left=margin, right=1-margin,
                        bottom=margin, top=1-margin)
    return fig, ax



fig, ax = axes_with_pixels(580, 80)  # Specify the Axes size in pixels

X = np.linspace(0, 10, 10)
Y0 = np.sin(X)
Y1 = np.cos(X)

plt.plot(X, Y0, label='min')
plt.plot(X, Y1, label='max')
plt.legend()
```

[image]

As you can see, the `Axes` (plot area) is exactly 580 * 80 pixels. (Note, the shown width of 581 pixels is due to the offset of the right edge.)

However, `axes_with_pixels` can be only used to set a single `Axes` with a specified pixels. If you want a figure to have multiple `Axes` with some specified pixels, then you have to consider  `wspace` and `hspace` in `subplots_adjust` to get the figure size.